# Concatenate string with array values

Tags: python, arrays

I'm using Python and want to be able to create an array and then concatenate the values with a string in a certain format. I'm hoping below will explain what I mean.

```
name_strings = ['Team 1', 'Team 2']
print "% posted a challenge to %s", %(name_strings)
```

Where each value from `name_strings` will be placed in the `%s` spot. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close, all you need to do is remove the comma in your example and cast it to a tuple:

```
print "%s posted a challenge to %s" % tuple(name_strings)
```

**Edit**: Oh, and add that missing `s` in `%s` as @falsetru pointed out.

Another way of doing it, without casting to tuple, is through use of the [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) function, like this:

```
print("{} posted a challenge to {}".format(*name_strings))
```

In this case, `*name_strings` is the python syntax for making each element in the list a separate argument to the `format` function.

Answer (score 4):

One way might be to expand the array in to the [str format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) function...

```
array_of_strings = ['Team1', 'Team2']
message = '{0} posted a challenge to {1}'
print(message.format(*array_of_strings))
#> Team1 posted a challenge to Team2
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove `,`:

   ```
   print "% posted a challenge to %s", %(name_strings)
   #                                 ^
   ```
2. The format specifier is incomplete. Replace it with `%s`.

   ```
   print "% posted a challenge to %s" %(name_strings)
   #      ^
   ```
3. [String formatting operation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#string-formatting-operations) require a tuple, not a list : convert the list to a tuple.

   ```
   name_strings = ['Team 1', 'Team 2']
   print "%s posted a challenge to %s" % tuple(name_strings)
   ```
4. If you are using Python 3.x, `print` should be called as function form:

   ```
   print("%s posted a challenge to %s" % tuple(name_strings))
   ```

---

Alternative using [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
name_strings = ['Team 1', 'Team 2']
print("{0[0]} posted a challenge to {0[1]}".format(name_strings))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
concatenated_value = ' posted a challenge to '.join(name_strings)
```